# django admin to edit foreign keys inline

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, geodjango

Is there a way to make 'GeoData' display inline in admin for 'Shop' and 'Park' objects?

(One Shop/Park can contain several locations)

```
# Location data
class GeoData(models.Model):
  lat = models.FloatField()
  lon = models.FloatField()
  description = models.TextField()

# Parent class for every object with location data
class GeoEntity(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=32)
  position = models.ForeignKey(GeoData)

class Shop(GeoEntity):
  tel = models.CharField(max_length=32)
  address = models.TextField()

class Park(GeoEntity):
  wifi = models.BooleanField()
  area = models.IntegerField()
```

I tried many options from google, but none of them worked.

Thanks.

Comment: you have to connect geodata to shop and park model so that admin will allow you to display inline for it

Comment: @duke_nukem were you able to solve this ?

Comment: As @catherine mentioned you have to connect shop/park with GeoData via ManyToMany relationship and then use inline you can follow this link for details (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding to your admin.py for those classes.  Try something like this.

```
 class ShopAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('tel', 'address', 'position')
```

This can be found in detail in the Djangobook admin chapter.
http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter06.html

Answer (score -1):

Dig you try filter_horizontal: http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter06.html ?

It only works with ManyToManyFields, so you have to change your models.